# How to communicate USB Port through MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am doing Project for my Final year Term work
Where I want to send digital data to Arduino -ATMega-328 Controller. 
My Data will be in the form like this in Matlab
`a=0001 b=0010 c=0011 d=0100 e=0101 f=0111`

Data can be transmitted with the help of USB Port. So question is how to transmit data over USb from MATLAB

Comment: First google hit on "Matlab arduino" looks well.

Answer (score 1):

If the interface to your controller is serial over USB, you can simply open the device port like any normal file, and then write to it:

```
datastring = 'a=0001 b=0010 c=0011 d=0100 e=0101 f=0111'
fileID = fopen(portname,'w');    // open port with write permissions
fprintf(fileId,'%s',datastring); // write text to port
```

If this is not the case, you may want to try [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27843-arduino-io-package-slides-and-examples) or [here](http://www.mathworks.com/academia/arduino-software/arduino-matlab.html).

Comment: I am trying to do serial communication with my MATLAB m file When I write program in command window i mean when it get execute step by step I am getting the out from the MATLAB. But when i write same command in mfile it is not being executed. My program is like this "move=serial('COM36') fopen(move) fwrite(move,'m') fclose "

Comment: what do you mean "not being executed"? what kind of error do you get.